# How to check if a value in exists in a column of cache query in django?

Tags: python, django, date

I am writing a django application where I create a model object and then bulk create data in the end. Here is my code:

```
date_list = [list of dates]
data = []
for date in date_list:
     my_row = Model1.objects.get(date=date)
     if not date in data:
         data.append(Model2(user_id=my_row.user_id, date = date))
Model2.objects.bulk_create(data)
```

This is where the error is: `if not date in data:` How do I search for object with my `date` in a list which looks like:

```
[ Model2(date = date), Model2(date = date), Model2(date = date),..]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you don't want to add a Model2 with a duplicate date, is that right? Can you just remove duplicate dates beforehand?

Comment: No, the whole point of this question is to focus on checking if the date exists in data list.

Comment: You should move that `my_row = Model1.objects.get(country='GB')`  you added outside of the loop so it doesn't fire off N queries.

Comment: Right, but you can guarantee that a date won't already exist in the list by removing duplicates beforehand.

Comment: Maybe, so how do I remove duplicate dates from the list?

Comment: date_list = set(date_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to find a `date` in a list of `Model2` - they are not the same objects. The Q&D solution would be to use another container to store and lookup dates already seens - preferably a `set()` because the containment test is much faster (O(1) instead of O(N)):

```
date_list = [list of dates]
data = []
date_seens = set()
for date in date_list:
     if date not in date_seens:
         data.append(Model2(date=date))
         date_seens.add(date)
```

But then since the goal is to not create more than one `Model2` instance for a given date, the much more efficient is to make `date_list` itself a `set`, which will garantee dates are uniques right from the start:

```
data = [Model2(date=date) for date in set(date_list)]
```

Note that this last solution won't preserve the `date_list` order, but I assume this is not important here.

Also note that none of this will garantee you don't have duplicate dates in your model's table - we deduplicate the dates from `date_list` but if you run the same script twice with the same dates you *will* have (at least) two distinct `Model2` rows for each date. If you want to enforce uniqueness of your models, you'll have to do it at the database level (with `unique=True` constraint on your model's `date` field), but then `bulk_create` will fail if one of your dates is already in the database...

Answer (score 1):

can you use set?

```
date_list = [list of dates]
for date in set(date_list):
    data.append(Model2(date = date))
Model2.objects.bulk_create(data)
```

Comment: No, the whole point of this question is to focus on checking if the date exists in data list.